# How do I save a multi-line(fasta format) as one line in textbox (C#)?

Tags: c#, textbox, fasta

I have a text with **FASTA format**. Such as the following text:

> SEQUENCE_1
>   MTEITAAMVKELRESTGAGMMDCKNALSETNGDFDKAVQLLREKGLGKAAKKADRLAAEG
>   LVSVKVSDDFTIAAMRPSYLSYEDLDMTFVENEYKALVAELEKENEERRRLKDPNKPEHK
>   IPQFASRKQLSDAILKEAEEKIKEELKAQGKPEKIWDNIIPGKMNSFIADNSQLDSKLTL
>   MGQFYVMDDKKTVEQVIAEKEKEFGGKIKIVEFICFEVGEGLEKKTEDFAAEVAAQL

I want to merge line. Such as the following text:

> SEQUENCE_1MTEITAAMVKELRESTGAGMMDCKNALSETNGDFDKAVQLLREKGLGKAAKKADRLAAEGLVSVKVSDDFTIAAMRSYLSYEDLDMTFVENEYKALVAELEKENEERRRLKDPNKPEHKIPQFASRKQLSDAILKEAEEKIKEELKAQGKPEKWDNIIPGKMNSFIADNSQLDSKLTLMGQFYVMDDKKTVEQVIAEKEKEFGGKIKIVEFICFEVGEGLEKKTEDFAAEAAQL

I used to this code:

`textbox.Text = textbox.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");`

But nothing happened. Please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you want

```
  textbox.Text = textbox.Text.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "");
```

Since the text uses `\n` (or `\r`) as a line separator.